# Get number of distinct elements in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Distinct List of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019854/java-distinct-list-of-objects)

i have a sorted array of huge size (around 3000 strings) ,
 i need to create an object for each distinct string , 
therefore i need create an array of objects with the size equal to distinct strings in the original array.

any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019854/java-distinct-list-of-objects do what you need ?

Comment: I seriously doubt 3000 can be considered a huge size. Maybe if it was 1 million ...

Comment: i know 3000 is not huge , but i meant processing time wise .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you need the distinct elements and not just the number, you may use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

A Set is:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

You keep adding your elements to the set, and then just look at what the set contains.

Something similar to this:

```
public static String[] getDistinct(String[] input) {

    Set<String> distinct = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String element : input) {
        distinct.add(element);
    }

    return distinct.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Usage:

```
String[] input = new String[] {"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "d"};
String[] distinct = getDistinct(input);

for(String element : distinct) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Result:

> d b c a

Note that the order of the elements may not be preserved.

To find the number of the distinct elements, use:

```
getDistinct(input).length
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a Set is what you're looking for.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood that. I adjusted the answer to sum up the distinct strings.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
previous = Null
sum_size = 0

for (String current: yourarray) {

    if (!current.equals(previous)) {
        sum_size += current.size()
    }
    previous = current
}
```

sum_size is the added size of distinct elements in your array.

Comment: He's not looking to count how many distinct objects there are

Comment: ok, I misunderstood that. I adjusted the answer to sum up the distinct strings